# Magento 2 Luma theme menu navigation not showing

Tags: magento2, navigation

I migrated to magento 2 and enabled the luma theme, but now i don't see any navigation anymore....

https://www.huurhulp.nl/tricot-stoffen.html

My categories are not showing up.

Comment: Hmm indeed it's weird... Make sure you have active your categories, and set Yes for the "include in navigation menu" field.
Your links doesn't work. If you have already check config, we need more details.
Regards Sony

Comment: I figured out that when i turn of varnish, the menu is back. So it has to do something with the varnish cashing....

Comment: I've experienced the same thing when I mistakenly had my M2 instance configured to use Varnish, but Varnish wasn't running. If you view source and see a `<esi:include></esi:include>` tag ... then you know that Varnish isn't working ... as it should take the "src" attribute and include it. You can switch your full page cache type to the built-in one to verify.

Answer (score 2):

When you have Varnish (or Fastly for Magento Cloud) selected as your FPC application, Magento outputs the category navigation as an `<esi:include />`.

For an `<esi:include />` to be processed, the web requests in the browser have to go through varnish or else you will see no navigation. You'll only see the reference to the esi include in the source of the page. That is because the browser and web server don't know how to process `<esi:include />` elements.

Seeing in your comments, it sounds like you have the full page cache configured to use varnish. This might be the ultimate goal as it helps a lot with caching performance, but until then you could switch back to the built-in cache.

Cli command to switch to Built-in cache:

```bash
// 1 - Built-in Cache
// 2 - Varnish
php bin/magento config:set system/full_page_cache/caching_application 1
```

Comment: How can we resolve this, I am using varnish and memcached. Top menu not showing

Comment: @VinaySikarwar You'll need to make sure requests to the site are going through Varnish first

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the categories are under the default category and you have set Yes for include in the navigation